# Is curl required?

Tags: http, curl, wp-remote-request

My admin panel is very slow I've tried to debug the issue. I nailed it to the function `wp_remote_post` and an internal error message thrown by curl on this line

```
return new WP_Error( 'http_request_failed', curl_error( $handle ) );
```

I wonder what would have happened if I uninstalled curl. Can WordPress use other mechanisms to make http requests or is curl required?

Answer (score 1):

For the record, I have uninstalled curl and wordpress was working on seamlessly.

So I confirm that curl is not a dependency of wordpress.

However, some plugins may require curl.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress themselfes claim to not require anything else than:

- Nginx or Apace .
- PHP 5.2.4 or greater.
- MySQL or some other database that connects to PHP's `mysqli_connect(...)`, like MariaDB.
- Some way to rewrite requests like Apache mod_rewrite.

No requirements for curl is mentioned, so I would assume that it will use other methods if curl is not avaible.

Refrence: https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/